# Как выбрать весь код по селектору jquery html()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

```js
$(function() {
  var takeHtml = $('#take').html();
  alert(takeHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="take">
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как в переменную *takeHtml* положить HTML не только, который находится в блоке, а и код самого блока. Т.е. результат должен быть не такой:

```
<td>QWER1</td>
<td>QWER1</td>
<td>QWER1</td>
<td>QWER1</td>
```

А такой:

```
<tr id="take">
   <td>QWER1</td>
   <td>QWER1</td>
   <td>QWER1</td>
   <td>QWER1</td>
</tr>
```

Вариант с `"" + takeHtml + ""` не желателен, ведь tr может содержать кучу других селекторов.

Comment: Десять раз перечитал, так и не понял...

Comment: @Air, я порешал :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На JQuery это делается хаком, добавляя ваш элемент в пустой `div`.

```
$('<div>').append($('#take').clone()).html();
```

Так же эту задачу легко решить на чистом JavaScript

```js
var el = document.getElementById("take");
alert(el.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="take">
<span>xxx</span>
yyy
</div>
<span>lll</span>
```

Comment: Конечно всё хорошо, но было бы классно, если бы вы собственный код вставляли, а не копировали с других вопросов :)

Comment: @Yuri пример на JavaScript полностью мой. Пример на JQuery я скопировал, но не вижу в этом проблемы, если бы я знал как это сделать на JQuery более компактно или красиво, я бы написал свой код.

Answer (score 2):

В JQuery такой функции нет и решается она с помощью костыля. Предлагаю решить используя чистый JS

```js
$(function() {
  var takeHtml = $('#take').get(0).outerHTML;
  alert(takeHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="take">
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: В каком месте тут *чистый* JS?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `.outerHTML` :D